# Apply multiple filter on column using nested tuple

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples, filtering

Trying to add an addition condition to a tuple filter....

Current working tuple filter without additional condition (discussed later):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['A',23], ['D',50], ['C',32], ['D',21], ['D',24], ['B',20], ['C',68], ['A',52], ['A',41],[ 'D',44], ['B',29], ['B',70], ['B',33], ['C',56], ['A',72]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['group', 'age'])

group_mask = {(20, 30): 'A', (25, 30): 'B', (65, 70): 'C', (40, 50): 'D'}

df['range'] = df['group'].map({v:k for k, v in group_mask.items()})
df['in_range'] = (df['range'].str[0] <= df['age'])  &  (df['age'] <= df['range'].str[1])

#filtered
df = df[df['in_range']]
df.drop(columns=['range', 'in_range'], inplace=True)
```

The above code filters dataframe to rows where age is equal to, or between the ranges set out in the group_mask for each corresponding group.
Thus producing the following output...

```
      group   age
0     A       23
1     D       50
6     C       68
9     D       44
10    B       29
```

However, there is an additional condition (column) which I need to consider; column `gender`. Depending on the `gender`, the `age` filter range for the `group` differs

The data has now been amended to include this additional column:

```
data = [['A', 'male', 23], ['D','female',50], ['C','male',32], ['D','male',21], ['D','female',24], ['B','female',20], ['C','male',68], ['A','male',52], ['A','male',41],[ 'D','male',44], ['B','female',29], ['B','female',70], ['B','female',33], ['C','female',56], ['A','female',72]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['group', 'gender', 'age'])
```

However, adjusting the existing `group_mask` tuple filter to now include 'gender' dependent ranges is where I'm stuck, as seen below.

I have tried changing from....

```
group_mask = {(20, 30): 'A', (25, 30): 'B', (65, 70): 'C', (40, 50): 'D'}
```

to....

```
group_mask  = {(((20, 30), 'A') , 'male' ), (((25, 30), 'B') , 'male' ), (((65, 70), 'C') , 'male' ), (((40, 50), 'D'), 'male' ), \
(((60, 80), 'A') , 'female'), (((15, 30), 'B'),  'female'), (((50, 60), 'C'), 'female'), (((30, 40), 'D'), 'female' )}
```

..followed by then reapplying the `map` and filter....

```
df['range'] = df[['group', 'gender']].map({v:k for k, v in group_mask .items()})
df['in_range'] = (df['range'].str[0] <= df['age'])  &  (df['age'] <= df['range'].str[1])
```

However, it raises an error message `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'`

Firstly, I am not sure whether the revised `group_mask` is fomatted correctly and secondly I am not sure how to correct the `map` function.

In need of help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you mean `df[['group', 'gender']].map({v:k for k, v in group_mask .items()})` instead of `df['group', 'gender'].map({v:k for k, v in group_mask .items()})`?

Comment: Also, `group_mask` is not a dictionary, right? What do you mean by `group_mask .items()`?

Comment: when I tried `df[['group', 'gender']].map({v:k for k, v in group_mask .items()})` I got the following error message.....`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'`

Comment: Yes, it doesn't entirely solve the problem but it solves part of the problem because when you are querying for two columns you need to use a list such as `df[['group', 'gender']]` instead of `df['group', 'gender']`.

Comment: "Also, group_mask is not a dictionary, right? What do you mean by group_mask .items()?" the group_mask was used in the first example at the top and now I want to add `gender` as a key or condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `group_mask` to be something like this:

```py
group_mask = {(30, 40): ('D', 'female'), (25, 30): ('B', 'male'), (40, 50): ('D', 'male'), (65, 70): ('C', 'male'), (60, 80): ('A', 'female'), (20, 30): ('A', 'male'), (15, 30): ('B', 'female'), (50, 60): ('C', 'female')}
```

And to apply the map, you can have something like this:

```py
df['range']=df.apply(lambda x: [(x[0],x[1])], axis=1, result_type='expand')[0].map({v:k for k, v in group_mask .items()})
df['in_range'] = (df['range'].str[0] <= df['age'])  &  (df['age'] <= df['range'].str[1])
```

Comment: This worked!! However, data originally a ref column `col_ref` which I removed. When the `col_ref`  is included (which I need), code produces empty df...
I tried changing `result_type` to `broadcast` to get all original columns, but produces error `ValueError: too many dims to broadcast`

Comment: @DiopChopra Can you replace `(x[0],x[1])` with `(x[1],x[2])` and try running it?

Comment: That worked, but what if I want all the other original columns as well, how can I get them back into df? There are 20 others

Comment: You are trying to map based on the group and gender values. So, make sure you select group and gender columns correspondingly. In your first case, group was in first column and gender was in second column, and therefore `(x[0],x[1])` would work. In your second case, group is in second column and gender is in third column, and that's why `(x[1],x[2])` would work. Now, in the new data frame if you have group in the m-th column and gender in the n-th column, then you can use `(x[m-1],x[n-1])`.

Comment: `(x[m-1],x[n-1])` sorry but I do not understand this. There are in fact 10 columns in the  original `df`. The `group` column is the 2 column (column index 1) and the `gender` is the 3rd column (column index 2) - How would i write that?

Comment: You can try: `(x[1],x[2])`

Comment: its returning empty

Comment: OMG! Aplogies and and great big thank you for your patience and assistance. Finally discovered the issue - a user error on my end

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad that it worked. And thanks for informing that it worked. :)